# SQL Query takes more than 3h - too long

Tags: query-optimization, database-administration, oracle19c

I have a TableSpace with a capacity of 1GB and I send a query about PL SQL every month.

Here is my configuration

| Tables | RowNumbers | DBOs | TableSpaces |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tbl_A | 400 million rows | DB_E | TS_Y |
| Tbl_B | 60 million rows | DB_F | TS_Z |
| Tbl_C | 5 million rows | DB_F | TS_Z |

I want to fill the resultset to this table :

| Table | RowNumbers | DBOs | TableSpaces |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tbl_D | ~10 million rows | DB_F | TS_Z |

Here is my Query :

```
CREATE TABLE DB_F.Tbl_D TABLESPACE TS_Z AS
SELECT
        SUM(DURATION) AS DURATION,
        DATMOUNT,
        NUMDOC,
        TYPDOC,
        TEAM,
        MONTH
FROM (

SELECT DISTINCT
                Tbl_B.NUMDOC,
                Tbl_B.TYPDOC,
                Tbl_C.TEAM,
                Tbl_C.MONTH,
                Tbl_A.DATEX,
                Tbl_A.DATEX + 6 - (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(Tbl_A.DATEX,'D') = '7' THEN '0' ELSE TO_CHAR(Tbl_A.DATEX,'D') END) AS DATMOUNT,
                Tbl_A.HOURSFIRST,
                Tbl_A.DURATION

FROM DB_F.Tbl_B Tbl_B
    
    INNER JOIN  DB_F.Tbl_C Tbl_C ON Tbl_B.IDAFFA = Tbl_C.ID_NAME
    INNER JOIN  DB_E.Tbl_A ON Tbl_A.NUMDOC = Tbl_B.NUMDOC
    
WHERE
                Tbl_A.NUMDOC = Tbl_B.NUMDOC
                AND TO_CHAR(Tbl_C.FIRSTDAY,'YYYYMM' ) <=  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE,12),'YYYYMM' ) 
                AND TO_CHAR(Tbl_C.FIRSTDAY,'YYYYMM' ) > TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE,-13),'YYYYMM' ) 
                AND Tbl_A.DATEX + 6 - (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(Tbl_A.DATEX,'D') = '7' THEN '0' ELSE TO_CHAR(Tbl_A.DATEX,'D') END) <= Tbl_C.LASTDAY
                AND Tbl_A.DATEX + 6 - (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(Tbl_A.DATEX,'D') = '7' THEN '0' ELSE TO_CHAR(Tbl_A.DATEX,'D') END) >= Tbl_C.FIRSTDAY
                AND Tbl_B.DATE_M <= Tbl_C.LASTDAY
                AND Tbl_B.DATE_I >= Tbl_C.LASTDAY
                AND Tbl_B.IDAFFA = Tbl_C.ID_NAME
                AND (Tbl_A.NATURE = 'IT' OR Tbl_A.NATURE = 'IS')
)
GROUP BY
        NUMDOC,
        TYPDOC,
        TEAM,
        DATMOUNT,
        MONTH;
```

Here the Query Plan with reduced Data because it takes too much time :

[image]

I will send later a second Plan

All where clauses of all 3 tables (Tbl_A, Tbl_B, Tbl_C) are indexed  in a separate tablespace.

Unfortunately, the import of the data takes almost 3 hours, which is very long for 10 million lines. When the data is imported, I only have 100MB of free space in my tablespace.

**Question**: does the import of the data take so long because there is not enough free memory (100MB) available? Or if there is a possibility to change the query more efficient?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The query you posted appears to be invalid.  There are two tables, for example, aliased `Tbl_C`.  And you're mixing old style joins with standard SQL 99 joins which isn't invalid but is very weird.  You haven't included the query plan which is going to be necessary for any sort of tuning effort.  And saying that the `where` clauses are indexed doesn't tell us a lot-- there are lots of ways to interpret that from a single index on each table that includes every column that is used to join or filter the table to a bunch of individual indexes.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answers.
I have posted a picture where on the last line the table Tbl_A doesn't execute the index so there is no Fast Full Scan. Do you have an idea, why my query doesn't use the index?

Comment: It might help to look at the cardinality estimates used by the optimiser as well. The query plan you show is a good start but other Oracle provided tools provide a cleaner and more obvious guide to what might be the issue. Maria provides a good explanation here.
https://sqlmaria.com/2020/11/03/explain-the-explain-plan-cardinality-estimates/